# php run exe throght exec in web but can't run gui

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, exec

First I'm sorry for my English..
I want to run a command throught exec to open a program.

for example: 
I want to open a txt file D:\text.txt
test.php

```
exec('D:\text.txt');
```

I use cmd to run this php file, it can open text.txt.
but when I run this php file in web server,it can't work.
the file can't open but i find a process named notepad.exe in Task Manager.
I tried a lot of method to resolve it but all ware failed.

My system: windows 7

php server : wampserver

user: Administrator

This web is only run in local.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#Hcom43917

Comment: @Bob It's not useful. result is same.and after I tried to make my web server's executable to interact with desktop and run my program, a window was popup and after I clicked the button ,the notepad appeard.but I don't want to confirm every time...

Answer (score 0):

Now I know how to resolve this problem.
This code can open file on my work computer, but can't on myself computer.
After I searched lots of, I fount it is related to os service.
On my work computer, the xampp is copy from other computer, and apache runs without os service, after I install apache service, it also doesn't work.

So I think if I konw how to run apache without service, this problem will be resolved.